# Check for a QMessageBox and close it

Tags: c++, qt, qmessagebox

I need to automate gui tests in c++ qt using qtest (in eclipse)
I have given a function that adds some tabs to a tabwidget (up to max 9) and if you try to open a 10th tab, a QMessageBox appears:

```
QMessageBox::critical(this, "MAX9",
tr("Only a maximum of 9 tabs can be opened.\n"));
```

Because the whole menu with the "add tab" function and everything is private, I had to access the method using slots and signals from my testclass.

Now my question is, is there a way I can check whether there are ANY QMessageBoxes open and if yes, automatically close them?

EDIT: SOLVED
I put vahancho's solution into a method (CloseMessageBoxes) and I've created a timer in my testmethod that calls CloseMessageBoxes() method then:

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(CloseMessageBoxes()));
timer->start(5000);
```

There are multiple messageboxes appearing but all are closing themselves after 5 seconds.

Comment: OMG I NEED THIS ANSWER IN PYTHON

Comment: @FoggyMindedGreenhorn Can you please ask a different question for the Python version and share the link? I have an answer that might help and I dont want to dilute this question with that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you can find all message boxes as they are top level widgets, and close them one by one:

```
QWidgetList topWidgets = QApplication::topLevelWidgets();
foreach (QWidget *w, topWidgets) {
    if (QMessageBox *mb = qobject_cast<QMessageBox *>(w)) {            
        QTest::keyClick(mb, Qt::Key_Enter);
    }
}
```

However the problem is that message box is a modal dialog and it blocks the main event loop. You need to find a way to execute the code above after a message box appeared.

Comment: yes, this is why I asked to automatically close them, I only have this one testclass and I don't see a way to execute this

Comment: @RandomDisplayName, what if you use timer that will close all message boxes after the certain amount of time?

Comment: I don't really know how I do this :S I mean when I first set a timer in my method and then the messagebox appears, the timer freezes doesn't he?

Comment: @RandomDisplayName, what prevents you from trying it? Just start a timer in your gui thread and see whether it timed out while a message box is shown.