# Qt QMessageBox Unit test

Tags: c++, qt, testing, qmessagebox

I'm trying to do unit tests in qt of Gui. It fills correctly data in `QLineEdit`.
The problem is that I cannot close automatically a `QMessageBox` which is called in a method that is tested. I have to push `ok` button manually in the test app.
How can I solve it?

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23076738/c-qt-check-for-a-qmessagebox-and-close-it

Comment: It doesn't work for me your solution. Why?

Comment: What does not work? What you did and what you get? Please notice the timer usage.

Comment: I tried to use the part of the code that you wrote in the discussion, but it doesn't close the window with the message box